# How to select the column has value other than the header in google sheets?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, google-query-language

I got responses from Google form into Google Spreadsheet. I want to filter out the "Weekend" and "Workday". For the "Weekend" days, I only want to select the columns that are related to "Weekend", because of the different sections and conditions on Google Form, if the person selects "Weekend", it will not ask the question "Did you sign in?" "Date" and "Did you check emails", now I want to exact weekend to another sheet, and select the columns that have questions only related with weekends. [Here is my sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nu0B0.png)

My idea to do this is select rows that are "Weekend" on column D then put them into another sheet,  How to select the columns only has "Weekend", which looks [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rRxZ0.png). How can I only select the column that has value so that I select it doesn't need to select those blank questions?

Comment: Instead of using `*` in select statement of query, use something like this `Select A,B,C,D,H,I,J where D = 'Weekend'`, does this solve your problem?

Comment: No, I still have more other columns and questions to ask, like if there is an hoilday under the days. Then I have three more columns that I could separate it.

Comment: As @vector's comment says, you'll have to select only the applicable columns instead of using the * since using the * it will return all columns. Unless you want to use app script where you will create another array where D = 'Weekend' and only push to the new array columns with data.

Comment: You can also build the custom select statement, based on condition. Just use `if` and build the statement

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(QUERY(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(Data!A:J)," ","~"),"Where Col4 = 'Weekend'",1),,9^9)))," ","|"),"~"," "),"Select Col1 where "&"Col1 <>'"&TEXTJOIN("' and Col1 <> '",true,trim(Data!1:1))&"'"),"|")))
```

here is the [**link**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/17Ee4Y8wPTHVCYAMSXfMydC32FuUTk9cZ6SbdvhpI-Jw/edit#gid=0) of sample sheet for you reference.